# The error of 'Duplicate string index signature' at Reactjs with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I made an object using Typescript at Reactjs.
There is a code below.
But it makes this error in UserInformation data from password to lastname.
Could you give me some advice?

> Duplicate string index signature

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export interface ISignStore {
  email: string,
  password: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  handleInput(e: any): void,
  handleSubmit(e: any): void
}

export class SignStore implements ISignStore {
  @observable
  UserInformation: {
    [email: string]: '',
    [password: string]: '',
    [firstName: string]: '',
    [lastName: string]: ''
  };

  @action
  handleInput = (e: any): void => {
    [e.target.id] = e.target.value;
  };

  @action
  handleSubmit = (e: any): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.UserInformation);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you know what the types of a particular object, TypeScript allows you to use interfaces like you have defined with `ISignStore`. Following the same pattern for `UserInformation`, the type would be:

```
interface IUserInformation {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

On the other hand, the syntax you have currently used is called as an [Index Signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

```
interface IObject {
  [k: number]: string
}
```

This is basically saying that you have an object, but you don't know what keys it would have; But you are sure that the key would be a number and value would be a string. The variable `k` here is just a placeholder, you can use anything in that place. So, by the merit of this, there is no usage where there should be a second key for `k2: number`. Because `k: number` has already covered that case.

This is the error you are getting having defined, `email`, `password` and `firstName` as keys in index signature.  They are just duplicate for `string` based key.

Comment: But what if I *did* want to have a second index signature because the data assigned to it is different? In my example, I'm trying to structure state for Redux, and I'll use `byId` and `allIDs` as a pattern. But the `Id` and `IDs` portions of those may changes to, say, `byName` and `allNames`. Can that be accomplished? (Maybe I should start a new question).

Answer (score -2):

```
 UserInformation: {
    [email]: '',
    [password]: '',
    [firstName]: '',
    [lastName]: ''
  };
```

I think you already assign type to those things.