# Duplicate string index signature.ts(2374)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Following is the type that I wanted to create with index signature in TypeScript.

```
export interface LoginState {
    account: {
              [userName: string]: string;
              [password: string]: string;
           };
}
```

But, I'm getting an error as stated in the title of this question.

The tool complains/highlighted the password field.

[image]

I found the following answer: 
[The error of 'Duplicate string index signature' at Reactjs with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321867/the-error-of-duplicate-string-index-signature-at-reactjs-with-typescript)
But that didn't help for my problem.

Can anyone point me the mistake I have done here?

Please feel free to ask if require further clarifications.

Cheers,
RSF

P.S adding complete component implementation:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { User } from "./../interfaces/User";
import { SecurityService } from "./../services/SecurityService";

export interface LoginProps {
  onLogged: (user: User) => void;
}

export interface LoginState {
  currentUser: User | null;
  account: {
         [userName: string]: string;
         [password: string]: string;
  };
}

export class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, LoginState> {

   constructor(props: LoginProps) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
          currentUser: null,
               account: {
               userName: "",
               password: ""
           }
        };
   }

  handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault();
  };

  handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      let account = { ...this.state.account };
      account[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value;
 };

 render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="userName">Username</label>
        <input
          autoFocus
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="userName"
          id="userName"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="password"
          id="password"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: You can only have one string index signature, and since there is no code associated with it is usually enough. What are you trying to accomplish, we might be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: If you just want properties there is no need for an index signature `{ username : string, password : string} ` will do

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, Thank you very much for your prompt reply.

I just want to handle changes within one function.
e.g

 handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[e.currentTarget.name.toString()] = e.currentTarget.value;
  };

Cheers, RSF

Comment: And what happens when you do that, is there an error?  It helps to provide a [mcve], ideally one which can be dropped into any IDE with no dependencies, or a link to a web-based IDE with the necessary dependencies.  Otherwise any answers you get are guesses.  My guess is: you're going to need to use type assertions or `e.currentTarget` is going to need to be narrowed via assertion or type guard to `{name: "username", value: string} | {name: "password", value: string}`.

Comment: @jcalz, Thanks for your feedback.
It's compile time error. As per the attachment you can see the IDE has underlined the error.
But I will give it a go with your suggestion.
However, I don't think I would get this error if I use JSX instead TSX. Limitation in TS? any thoughts appriciated.

Comment: Sorry, I was saying, "what happens when you do the code in your comment", not "what happens when you try to use two index signatures", which is an error.  @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's suggestions are good ones for the question as stated.  But if you have a use case for it, it should be in the question as a [mcve] and not in comments.

Comment: @jcalz,
Thanks for your feedback.
I have update the question wiht the component codebase.
Hope this helps to understand the context. cheers, RSF

Comment: Maybe someone with reactjs in their IDE can help you.  Or you can get that code into a linkable web IDE with and then anyone with a web browser can help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

> Similarly to how we can use interfaces to describe function types, we can also describe types that we can “index into” like a[10], or ageMap["daniel"]. Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing

When you use `index types` you are just telling typescript what return type you get when a custom type is indexed.

So you just need to tell Typescript that when you index `account` with a string type, a string type will be returned. That's all.

```
export interface LoginState {
  currentUser: User | null;
  account: {
      // Tells Typescript that a string index on account would return a string
      [k: string]: string;

      username: string;
      password: string;
      address: string;
      anotherField: string;
  };
}
```

By defining it like this:

```
[userName: string]: string;
[password: string]: string;    // This is a duplicate string index
```

You are doing this:

```
[k1: string]: string;
[k2: string]: string;    // This is a duplicate string index
```

Which is wrong because you're telling Typescript the same thing twice: *If you index account with a string, you'll get a string. If you index account with a string, you'll get a string.*

Later, if you wanted to introduce  `number` type fields called `id` and `age` to `account`, your definition would look like this:

```
export interface LoginState {
  currentUser: User | null;
  account: {
      // Tells Typescript that a string index on account would return a string OR a number
      [k: string]: string | number;

      username: string;
      password: string;
      address: string;
      anotherField: string;
      id: number;
      age: number;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you @PrashanD, sounds promissing.
Basically we can defined a union type for the index?

Comment: Yes you can, the typescript handbook I linked has some interesting examples

Comment: Thanks @PrashanD!